# Verify JWT ES256 by Apple Notification C# [Sandbox]

Tags: c#, jwt

I would like just to verify JWT from Apple Pay server notification.
You can see the JWT structure on the screenshot from the jwt.io website.

So, I took the first certificate from the x5c collection in the header, and convert it to the object X509Certificate2, then I get the public key in the ECDsa format and try to verify the token.

Did I implement this correctly in terms of security?
Should I validate a chain of three certificates after verifying the token?

I will be grateful for any information.

```
    private static Dictionary<string, string> GetClaimsByToken(string jwtToken)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(jwtToken);
        token.Header.TryGetValue("x5c", out object x5c)
        var certeficatesItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<string>>(x5c.ToString());

        ValidateJWS(tokenHandler, jwtToken, certeficatesItems.First());

        return token.Claims.ToDictionary(c => c.Type, v => v.Value);
    }

    private static void ValidateJWS(JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler, string jwtToken, string publicKey)
    {
        var certificateBytes = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(publicKey);
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes);
        var eCDsa = certificate.GetECDsaPublicKey();

        TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(eCDsa),
        };

        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwtToken, tokenValidationParameters, out var securityToken);
    }
```

[image: JWT from Apple]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know C# but today I stumble across this problem too.
It seems so after you validate jwt token, you have to validate a chain of certificates. You need to download certificates from Apple(root and intermediate). You can find these certificates on apple site: https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/.

You need to download them and validate them against the ones found in the x5c header.  You can find more info on apple developer forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691464